# Calling a setter via craft.app in Twig

Tags: templating, classes

apologies if this has been asked, I don’t seem to be able to find the solution.

What is the correct way to call craft.app.session.set in a Twig template (or any other setter function for that matter)? I can’t find a working example in the docs for anything other than getters.

To expand, this causes an error:

```
{# grab initial value, it is empty #}
{% set mySession = craft.app.session.get("mySession") %}
{{ "mySession = #{mySession}" }}

{# set value to 'someValue' - this will cause the error #}
{% craft.app.session.set("mySession", "someValue") %}

{# grab value again, it should now be 'someValue' #}
{% set mySession = craft.app.session.get("mySession") %}
{{ "mySession = #{mySession}" }}
```

However this works as expected:

```
{# grab initial value, it is empty #}
{% set mySession = craft.app.session.get("mySession") %}
{{ "mySession = #{mySession}" }}

{# set value to 'someValue' #}
{% set somePointlessVariable = craft.app.session.set("mySession", "someValue") %}

{# grab value again, it’s now 'someValue' #}
{% set mySession = craft.app.session.get("mySession") %}
{{ "mySession = #{mySession}" }}
```

Surely I don’t need to create some pointless variable just to use the setter function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm curious to know your use case for this, but have you tried using Twig's `do` tag?

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/do.html

i.e. `{% do craft.app.session.set("mySession", "someValue") %}`

Comment: Thanks, clearly it’s the Twig docs I need to spend more time in.